# clearing all fields in html form except one, and adding a value to the exceptional field

Tags: jquery

I use this jquery to clear (not reset) all the fields on a form:

```
<script>
function clear_form_elements(ele) {

$(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
            $(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
});

}

</script>
```

One of the fields in the form is named 'data1'. I have not been able to, after I clear the form, then, set a value in 'data1' to the value I want.

Comment: after clearing all of them ,you can set the value only for the exceptional one

Comment: Did you do: `case 'radio': this.checked = false;}}).end().find('data1').val('your_val')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clear all the elements, do:

```
$(ele).find('[name=data1]').val("defaultvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add reset type button inside your form so that on clicking it all values in the fields get cleared.

```
<input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

And, add the value to the field you want as:

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
    $("input[name='data1']").val("Your Value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button inside your form so that all values in the input fields will be cleared `OnClick` event.

```
$('#posting_comment')[0].reset();
```